# pthread_cancel don't work under solaris

Tags: c, pthreads, solaris

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char a[]="Hello";

void * thread_body(void * param) {
        while(1)
                printf("%s\n", param);
}

int main(int argc,  char *argv[]) {
        pthread_t threadHello;
        int code;
        pthread_create(&threadHello,  NULL,  thread_body,  a);
        pthread_cancel(threadHello);
        pthread_exit(0);
}
```

When I compile and run this under Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10), it doesn't stop. But under Linux it works as intended.

Comment: What value does `pthread_cancel()` return?

Comment: Have you [read the manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) and checked the cancellation state and type of the target thread?

Comment: @kerrek-sb yes, I read man-pages under linux and solaris.

Comment: @KingsIndian nothing is changed

Comment: @AlexeyMatveev Did you check the return values for those functions? They all succeeded?

Comment: @KingsIndian first of all, I think that this function should call from thread_body function, isn't it? Becaus in man-page wrote: "The pthread_setcancelstate() function  atomically  sets  the calling  thread's  cancellation state.."

Comment: @AlexeyMatveev That's right. Calling from main will change the main's state. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @KingsIndian When I call them from thread_body function thread was canceled, but when I remove call of pthread_testcancel and run program, it doesn't stop.

Comment: @KingsIndian if I run you version of program, it stop, but doesn't wrote "Hello".

Comment: @AlexeyMatveev That's because thread will not be cancelled until it reaches a cancellation point even if the state is .._ENABLE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16766/discussion-between-kingsindian-and-alexey-matveev)

Comment: Check this link for pthread_cancel http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html. I think it is informative one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per POSIX, `printf` (and all of stdio) *may* be a cancellation point. It is not required to be. I suspect Solaris just doesn't choose to make it one. Have you tried another function like `sleep` here?

If you really need `printf` to be cancellable, you'll probably need to implement your own `printf`-like function as a wrapper for `dprintf`, but that won't work so well if you're depending on the builtin locking functionality of stdio..