# Pthreads. Implementation of cancellation points

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, solaris

My question is related to this one [pthread_cancel don't work under solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455815/pthread-cancel-dont-work-under-solaris)

I have the same problem. I couldn't find `printf` implementation without `write`(write has cancellation point) call on the http://src.opensolaris.org (perhaps I didn't search enough)

I can't find information about cancellation points internals. How does asynchronous cancel work?(through signls or other way) How does defered cancel work?